# Is my MongoDB data model the right choice?

Tags: mongodb

I'm going to build my first project (genealogy database) with MongoDB and nodejs and I am asking myself, if my data model is the right choice:

people document (simplified):

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("123"),
   "modified": ISODate("2015-02-04T16:52:32.601Z"),
   "birth": ISODate("1995-02-04T16:52:32.601Z"),
   "name": "peter"
}, {
   "_id": ObjectId("456"),
   "modified": ISODate("2015-02-04T16:52:32.601Z"),
   "birth": ISODate("1999-02-04T16:52:32.601Z"),
   "name": "uschi"
}
```

relations document (simplified):

```
{
   "sourceID": ObjectId("123"),
   "targetID": ObjectId("456"),
   "type": "Married",
   "modified": ISODate("2015-02-04T16:52:32.599Z"),
   "startrelation": ISODate("2001-02-04T16:52:32.601Z"),
   "endrelation": ISODate("2007-02-04T16:52:32.601Z"),
   "_id": ObjectId("54d24e5033bfc203aaaad590") 
}
```

Yesterday I tried to retrieve a list with all people and their related people and got worries about my data model because I needed a lot of code to generate the following result:

```
items: [
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("123"),
        "modified": ISODate("2015-02-04T16:52:32.601Z"),
        "birth": ISODate("1995-02-04T16:52:32.601Z"),
        "name": "peter"
        "married": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("456"),
            "modified": ISODate("2015-02-04T16:52:32.601Z"),
            "birth": ISODate("1999-02-04T16:52:32.601Z"),
            "name": "uschi"
        }, ...]
    }, ...]
```

Is there are problem with that solution?

Comment: It took a lot of work to generate that result because you didn't store the data to make computing that result easy. Storing the data so your common and important queries are easy is the MongoDB paradigm. If you want more advice on how to design your schema, update the question with more information about what your common operations will be. Also check out the [MongoDB Manual data modeling examples and patterns](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your link. I removed my relations document and now store all relations within the people document.
I decided to store the names of the related people and the _id of the people object. Queries are much more easy now.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see with this solution is that you are using MongoDB to store relational data.  I have done this in the past and regretted it.  Consider using Postgres. It's a relational db but also has a feature called hstore which allows you to store and query arbitrarily structured json if your schema has some areas that may not be well defined.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that graph-database would be perfect match for you problem domain. 
This way you wont have to implement all the logic related to "relations" in your application. GraphDBs natively understand them.

i.e. [neo4j](http://neo4j.com/)

Graph databases allow for

- easily handle complex relations
- very quick traversal of relations
- fast searching for relationships of the type "friends of a friend" or who is Jim in relation to Janet

In general, if you are planning to query your data in various ways looking on relations, graph database is the way to go,